# WPF LinkLabel implementation strategy

Tags: wpf, animation, default, linklabel

I am attempting to create a LinkLabel control for WPF. Essentially, I'm going to create the LinkLabel from a TextBlock and handle MouseEnter, MouseLeave, and MouseLeftButtonUp events. In the back end I have a base class that has properties that you would expect to see with a LinkLabel. With most other clickable controls in WPF, there is a default MouseEnter animation where the control becomes Ice Blue. I would like to duplicate this behavior when the mouse cursor enters over the TextBlock. I'm not sure if I'm needing to derive from ButtonBase or something along those lines. I have a I am able to change the cursor to a hand, and handle the event for when the "LinkLabel" is clicked. If accessing this seemingly default color changing animations, then I just may have to resort to a simple foreground color swap without the smooth transition. If anyone has created a custom WPF LinkLabel before or has any advice into the matter your input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can create the equivalent of WinForms' LinkLabel right now using a combination of TextBlock and HyperLink:

```
<TextBlock>Here is a <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://example.com">link</Hyperlink></TextBlock>
```

You won't get the "ice blue" mouse-over effect, but you will get the hand cursor. I'm sure you can introduce your mouse-over effects using a simple style trigger.

The "NavigateUri" property works in navigation-style applications where the hyperlink is inside a Frame control. In a standard WPF application you'll want to handle the Hyperlink's Click event instead and use Process.Start to kick off a web browser with the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a style for a button and apply a style to a button whenever you want LinkLabel look.  Click event of button is used to perform a function when the text is clicked.

```
<Style x:Key="LinkLabelButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="CornflowerBlue"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="Transparent">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>                            
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>     
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkBlue"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="90"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

You can place above style in the Window.Resources so you can use it in entire window.

Then apply the style to a button whenever you want LinkLabel look.

```
<Button Name="LinkLabelLookALikeButton" Content="Text goes here" Style="{StaticResource LinkLabelButtonStyle}" Click="Event_Goes_Here">                        
                </Button>
```

Hope this helps!